# Understanding a set with volume zero

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to understand what is a set with zero volume is when we talk about integrals.

A few examples will really help.

Also, if we have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ when $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^3}$ and  $B \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$
can you immediately assume that the image has zero volume?

Comment: $f(A)$ will certainly have zero 3-dimensional volume, but nothing can be said about its 2-dimensional volume

Comment: Do you know about [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)? I think they answer the question you _actually meant_ to ask, in the negative.

Comment: @HenningMakholm no, that doesn't  what i mean. it's more about when we deal with multivariable function integration, some theorems use that as a requirement. I wish to understand that so I know how to use them

Comment: The process of defining volume consists on defining it for rectangles (of the corresponding dimension), then addition and subtraction of rectangles allow you to get volumes  of other figures like polygons. Finally one takes limits. Since for many shapes it is hard to put rectangles inside the useful thing is to cover them with rectangles and take limits of that (infimum). When that infimum is zero then you say that the volute of the figure is zero. Examples: $\emptyset$, one point, two points, a finite number of points, countably many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical example of a set with zero volume is a set which has a lower dimensionality than the space it is in. For example, $A=[0,1]\times \{0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ has zero volume, while $[0,1]^2$ does not. This means that no matter what two-variable function $f$ is, $$\int_A f(x,y) dxdy$$ will be equal to $0$.

It's worth noting that the set has zero volume **within $\mathbb R^2$**, even though the similar set $[0,1]$ has nonzero volume in $\mathbb R$.

---

For your second question, no, we cannot assume that. The image of $f$ can be, for example, $[0,1]^2$ which is has a volume of $1$ within $\mathbb R^2$.

There are cases where we know the image will have volume $0$, but only if the function is a continuous injective function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ where $m>n$.